# How to update values in one column based on values in another column? (Getting KeyError: "None of ...are in the [columns]"

Tags: python, pandas

I want to set values in one column to null (np.nan) if the value in the same row of another column is also null.

I'm trying:

```
df.loc[df[7].isnull(), df[10]] = np.nan
```

And I get error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['Density at 15 C (g/mL) (ASTM D5002)', 'Method', 'ASTM D5002)',\n       'ASTM D5002)', 'ASTM D5002)', 'ASTM D5002)', 'ASTM D5002)',\n       'ASTM D5002)', 'ASTM D5002)', 'ASTM D5002)',\n       ...\n       'ASTM D5002)', 'ASTM D5002)', 'ASTM D5002)', 'ASTM D5002)',\n       'ASTM D5002)', 'ASTM D5002)', 'ASTM D5002)', 'ASTM D5002)',\n       'ASTM D5002)', 'ASTM D5002)'],\n      dtype='object', length=297)] are in the [columns]"
```

I've tried removing "whitespaces", as I've seen that in another answer, by using:

```
delimiter=','
```

and have tried:

```
df[7]=df[7].replace(' ','')
```

And I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df.loc[df[7].isnull(),10] = np.nan
```

Example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
df[1]=[np.nan, 2 ,3 ,4, np.nan]
df[2]=[1,2,3,4,5]
print(df)

     1  2
0  NaN  1
1  2.0  2
2  3.0  3
3  4.0  4
4  NaN  5


df.loc[df[1].isnull(),2]=np.nan
print(df)

     1    2
0  NaN  NaN
1  2.0  2.0
2  3.0  3.0
3  4.0  4.0
4  NaN  NaN
```

---

**other cases:**

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
df[1]=[np.nan, 2 ,3 ,4, '']
df[2]=[1,2,3,4,5]
print(df)

     1  2
0  NaN  1
1    2  2
2    3  3
3    4  4
4       5

df.loc[df[1].isnull(),2]=np.nan
print(df)

     1    2
0  NaN  NaN
1    2  2.0
2    3  3.0
3    4  4.0
4       5.0
```

**as you see here you could not check only with isnull**

In this case you need:

```
df.loc[df[1].isnull()|df[1].eq(''),2]=np.nan
print(df)
     1    2
0  NaN  NaN
1    2  2.0
2    3  3.0
3    4  4.0
4       NaN
```